# Glitchy animation on SwiftUI's contextMenu(menuItems:preview:)

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-animation

I noticed there is always a glitchy animation the first time you run a context menu with a preview on SwiftUI. Subsequent triggers to the method work just fine, but the first one is really glitchy. Anybody else experiencing this? Tested on iOS 16.1 and 16.4 on an iPad.

Following a video demonstration and a minimal reproducible example.

[image]

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Image(systemName: "globe")
                .imageScale(.large)
                .foregroundColor(.accentColor)
            Text("Hello, world!")
                .contextMenu {
                    Text("Lol")
                } preview: {
                    Text("Preview")
                }

        }
        .padding()
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you describe the glitch in more detail? Maybe I'm missing something but this looks fine to me.

Comment: The animation is not supposed to do that big glitchy jump it does before showing the preview view. To see how it should look, long press on any item that triggers a context menu on iOS; the view slowly enlarges by a small amount, until the gesture triggers, and the enlarged view appears. At no point you get this huge oversized jump you see in the gif I posted above, which doesn't match the size of the long pressed view, or the resulting preview view.

Comment: I don't have an answer but I can't reproduce this on iPhone 16.4 or 17 simulators, using XC 15b8. The initial iPad animation is a bit different but not the full screen scale-down that you are seeing.